# Extract key/value pairs from FormCollection in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create a generic email module for our website that all forms can point to.  To make it dynamic we want to just grab the key value pairs of the form collection and print those in an email.

I found the following article on the subject but can't seem to get it to work.  I just get blank results.  What am I doing wrong?
http://www.dofactory.com/topic/1038/how-to-extract-key-values-from-formcollection-in-asp-net-mvc-action-method.aspx

Here is my code

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Send(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    foreach (var key in formCollection.Keys)
    {
        Body += "<p><b>";
        Body += key.ToString();
        Body += ":</b> ";
        Body += formCollection[key.ToString()];
        Body += "</p>";
    }
}
```

Form Sample:

```
<form role="form" action="/Email/Send" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Phone" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="hidden" id="Page" value="http://@Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]@Request.ServerVariables["URL"]">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-ar btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I should add the function does get called, as I do get a blank email with my subject.  I've left out other code that does the actual sending to save space.

Comment: Can you show your view that is calling this action? Did you invoke this action using the `POST` HTTP verb?

Comment: Added a sample form.  I know the form calls the function as I do get an email, its just blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input elements don't have `name` attribute on them. So nothing actually gets POSTed to the server - that's how HTML forms work. If you have used the `Network` tab of the developers toolbar in your browser you would have seen that.

So make absolutely sure that you place `name` attributes on your input elements:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Name">
```

Only input fields with `name` attribute will send their value to the server when the form is submitted and you will be able to retrieve their values in the `FormCollection` parameter.

Comment: Bah figures it's something so basic.  Guess I mixed up name and id.  Thanks